# Aptana .js files won't save without java dialogue

Tags: java, javascript, aptana

When I hit save in Aptana3 with a .js file I get a really annoying dialogue that says

```
 Save Failed
 Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered Java-like extensions
```

I can't seem to find any info about how to fix this.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I just made a mistake and hit ctrl+z and now the dialogue is no longer happening. Weird. Not sure if I should take Q down incase others are having the same issue.

Comment: As mentioned above, it seems this happens when there’s breakpoints – which, at least in my version, are little blue icons on the left of the document, and can be removed by double-clicking them.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This occurs when you have a breakpoint in your file, remove the breakpoint(s) and try to save again.

Comment: +1. After 1 hour battling with Eclipse (same issue) this was the neat solution.

Comment: That's right!!Goddamn eclipse. It happened to me without any special plug-in (however I did insert a js template notation in the file)

Comment: I've changed this to be the answer as the cut and paste solution I had marked before just effectively remove breakpoints.

Comment: But it does so?? And is it a bug or purposely designed mechanism??? I dont think its for user benefit anyway.. just wasting time with battling the most unexpected issue.

Answer (score 4):

Select All. Cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>) entire document, save, Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>) it back in, save.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all breakpoints in "breakpoints view" window

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the BreakPoint. But,Not any of the above solution worked for me. But, I copied the entire content to clipboard, and deleted the file, (which ultimately removes the breakpoint in that file :-) ) , then created a new file with the same name, and pasted the content from clipboard.

It now works for me!!!!!